# Magento2: Get Response in UI File Uploader Component

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, file-upload

I am uploading the Image from frontend using the below code:

```
<div class="upload-wrapper" data-bind="scope: 'uploader'">
<!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
</div>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
".upload-wrapper": {
   "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
       "components": {
           "uploader": {
               "component": "Magento_Ui/js/form/element/file-uploader",
               "template": "ui/form/element/uploader/uploader",
               "allowedExtensions": ["png", "jpg", "jpeg", "gif"],
               "uploaderConfig": {
                    "url": "<?php echo $block->getUrl('customer/account/family'); ?>"
               }
            }
        }
   }
 }
}
</script>
```

Image uploading is working from controller. From Controller I am passign the new uploaded image full path so that I can show the image on particular location.

My question is: how can I access the response from server side ?

I have also checked the `file-uploader.js`, there we have the event `done: this.onFileUploaded.bind(this),` But not sure how to call this here:

```
done: function (e, data) { 
    alert('uploaded');
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There're 2 possible ways to solve this. You can either opt to update the component, and thus get an access to it. Or, you can use your own element that extends the standard  `Magento_Ui/js/form/element/file-uploader`.

In the example below, we'll describe the second option, as it's more flexible and easier to implement.

Create a file:

```
app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/form/element/custom-file-uploader.js


define([
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/file-uploader'
], function (Element) {
    'use strict';

    return Element.extend({
        defaults: {
            fileInputName: ''
        },

        /**
         * Handler of the file upload complete event.
         *
         * @param {Event} e
         * @param {Object} data
         */
        onFileUploaded: function (e, data) {
            this._super(e, data);
            console.log(e); // test 
            console.log(data); // test 
            var response = data.result; // Here the response data are stored 
        }
    });
});
```

And make these changes in the component configuration:

```
<div class="upload-wrapper" data-bind="scope: 'uploader'">
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
</div>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
".upload-wrapper": {
   "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
       "components": {
           "uploader": {
               "dataScope": "custom.image",
               "component": "Vendor_Module/js/form/element/custom-file-uploader",
               "template": "ui/form/element/uploader/uploader",
               "allowedExtensions": ["png", "jpg", "jpeg", "gif"],
               "uploaderConfig": {
                    "url": "<?php echo $block->getUrl('mageworx_shippingrules/zone/upload'); ?>" 
               }
            }
        }
   }
 }
}
</script>
```

This will let you gain access to server response, as well as to any method of the file uploader.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Could you explain about this `"dataScope": "custom.image",`

Comment: Can I have multiple upload wrapper ? I am trying to separate using two class but both going on same URL.

Also if possible can you just guide how can we use this with uploader component for multiple option like Add more

Comment: Thanks I am able to solve that multiple wrapper. Only having issue with this only:

how can we use this with uploader component for multiple option like Add more

Comment: do you have any idea to use uploader component with add more option ? I am keep trying on this but still stuck

Comment: use "isMultipleFiles": true, for Multiple upload